# Spring-MVC: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, tomcat9

I created a simple spring-mvc project using Tomcat v9.0 server to just check if everything is working fine or not. From the main page when I hit the submit button, it is expected to see a message in the console but instead I get following message:

**HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Here is the code:
web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring-MVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring-MVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public void add() {
        System.out.println("Working!!");
    }
```

Spring-MVC-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.spring"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined form action here -

```
<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

is wrong.

The value of form action should be a URL. Depending on the protocol, host and the port number, this value would be different than just an `add`.

If you are running on localhost with http on port 8080, then this should be - `http://localhost:8080/add`.
It would differ based on what port you are running your app. If you don't know, it is likely 8080 since that is the default port for tomcat.

Comment: Is it necessary to write the complete URL, because I have not  done it in other projects still i got the required outputs.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK it is necessary to write the complete URL, also do you have these other projects on github because I would really like to see how form would work without a complete URL. And did my solution work?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not yet maintaining the github repository. The issue was regarding Tomcat v9, I downgraded to v8. As soon as i start maintaining the github repo, I will ping you. Thanks for the cosideration.

Comment: I have uploaded the project on github. Here's the link https://github.com/SatyamP07/Wallet-Web-App